# Sealed classes in Scala do not emit compiler warning anymore?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I have the following code:

```
sealed abstract class Expr;

case class Var(name: String) extends Expr;
case class Number(num: Double) extends Expr;

def describe(expr: Expr): Expr = expr match {
  case Var("*") => "multiply"
}
```

But seen as I have not covered all of the possible cases here( i.e. Number), I would expect that because Expr is a sealed class I would get a compiler warning, but I do not?

This code is from a Scala example using Scala 2.8, and I am using Scala 2.11, so has this feature been removed?

Thanks.

Comment: Probably not relevant to to absence of warning, but your describe is returning an ``Expr``, but you are returning a ``String``.

Answer (score 1):

Sure?

My example (removed semi colons, fixed def return type) :

```
$ cat X.scala
sealed abstract class Expr

case class Var(name: String) extends Expr
case class Number(num: Double) extends Expr

object Tst {
    def describe(expr: Expr) = expr match {
        case Var("*") => "multiply"
    }
}
```

and when compiling...

```
$ scalac X.scala
X.scala:7: warning: match may not be exhaustive.
It would fail on the following inputs: Number(_), Var((x: String forSome x not in "*"))
    def describe(expr: Expr) = expr match {
                                   ^
one warning found
```